# Can I get the email address of contacts from iCloud?

Tags: c#, icloud, icloud-api

I am building a C# application and I wish to gather a list of user contacts (Email, First name, last name). Using a direct login I was able to pull all information regarding the contacts except the emails. Is there a way for me to retrieve all contacts and their respective emails?

```
public void GetContacts(iCloudContactSortOrder sortOrder = iCloudContactSortOrder.FirstName)
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
            throw notConnectedException;

        // Set sort order
        ContactsSortOrder = sortOrder;

        // Create client
        NetClient netClient = new NetClient(sessionCookies, ICLOUD_HOME_URL, ICLOUD_HOME_URL);

        // Post client context data to the servers.
        string strResult = netClient.GET(ContactsMeCardUrl);
        ContactsMeCard = Deserialize<iCloudContactsMeCard>(strResult);

        // get contacts list.
        strResult = netClient.GET(ContactsStartupUrl);
        lastContactsResponse = Deserialize<iCloudContactsContactsResponse>(strResult);
    }
```

Comment: There's probably a very good reason why you can't get access to the email addresses.  Can you guess what it is?

Comment: I managed to access them, what was your thought behind the question? Security? Everybody are entitled to access to their own data.

Comment: You're trying to access... your own email address?

Comment: The users contacts emails.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the reason behind the lack of emails was that I haven't parsed the response correctly. There was a list inside the list of contacts pointing the emails.